# CAS authentication in localhost with an application running locally

Tags: authentication, grails, redirect, cas

I have my CAS setup locally. I have a grails application that is running locally as well. My CAS authentication is working. My CAS is running at this location

`http://localhost:8081/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check`

My grails application is running at `http://localhost:8080/CASTest/test/`

So when I go to my grails application i get redirected to CAS for login, however after login I getting I keep getting `evaluationException on hostUrl` in my CAS. I think the error is because of localhost in the service field in CAS, if i change this to test1.localhost it works, it redirects me to test1.localhost after authentication. Any ideas how i can redirect it back to my application that is running locally?

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) of your operating system to accept the chosen domain for your application as an alias to localhost, and then use that in your CAS configuration in development environment.

Check out the [Wikipedia entry for the hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) for the appropriate location in your system (if you are using Linux that would be `/etc/hosts`), and then add a line like:

```
127.0.0.1    test1.localhost
```

After that, you can use it in your CAS configuration for the development environment -- the `serviceUrl` configuration should point to something like `http://test1.localhost/CASTest/j_spring_cas_security_check`.

Hope it helps!